# trying to get the extended ascii value for all the characters of a word given

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to get the value of every character for a spanish word given.

The problem comes when the word contains some characters, like 'ñ, á, é' which are converted to a multi byte character.

I have also tested that for those special words, the encoding format is UTF-8 and the other normals are ASCII:

```
$word = 'ñoñería';
for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($word); $i++)
    echo mb_detect_encoding($word[$i]) . '<br />';
```

With the code bellow I was trying to get the ascii for each character of my word but doesn't work because of that multi byte:

```
$word = 'ñoñería';
for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($word); $i++){
    echo ord(iconv('utf-8', 'CP437', $word[$i]));
}
```

Any idea of how to solve it?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$word = 'ñoñería';
                                      //'CP850' <- also supported but not listed in php docs
$wordLatin = mb_convert_encoding($word, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($wordLatin); $i++){
    echo ord($wordLatin[$i]) . ' ';
}
```